# Checking the input field is empty or not

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have this field where already a value is retrieved in PHP from mysql.. Now when I press backspace and delete the value and check whether the field is empty or not, it's still showing the field is not empty. What is the way to solve it?

```
$('#button').click(function(){

var name = $('#namefield').val();

if(empty(name)){
alert("The field is empty"); 

// This alert is not happening even I empty the field, maybe because of the dynamic thing
}

});



<input type="text" value="<?php echo $name;  ?>" id="namefield" />
<input type="button" id="button" value="Click" />
```

Just in case when I delete the value . the inspect element does not change. It still contains the value.

Comment: have you tried name.length == 0 ?

Comment: What's `if(empty(name)){`?

Comment: Did you try `if(name.trim() !== '')`

Answer (score 1):

Unless you've defined `empty` as a function - it's not native. Check for blank text:

```
if (name.trim() == "") { alert("Empty") }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if(name.length){
 // not empty
}
```

And to cater for cases where the string is composed for only whitespaces you can do

```
if(name.trim().length)
{
  // not empty
}
```

Javascript doesnt have `empty()` like in your code. Thats most probably copied from your PHP code :)

Answer (score 0):

You may not use `empty()` such a way in jQuery. You can try this codes. `$.trim()` is used to remove leading & trialing space.

```
$('#button').click(function(){
    var name = $('#namefield').val();
    if(!$.trim(name)){
        alert("The field is empty");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Another jQuery-ish way to handle this - check whether the *field* is empty:

```
var name = $('#namefield');

if (name.is(':empty')) {
  alert("The field is empty"); 
}
```